# Content of iframe has disappeared

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe

The content of the iframe on this page has inexplicably vanished, leaving a big blank space.

I can see that the iframe is still present in the HTML, but for some reason its content is not displaying. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your browser's error console:

> Mixed Content: The page at '`https://www.cambridgeimmerse.com/subjects/economics-business/`' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource '`http://www.cambridgeimmerse.com/subjects-overview/`'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

You can't load HTTP content onto an HTTPS page. It risks leaking secure data.

Note that `https://www.cambridgeimmerse.com/subjects-overview/` **redirects** to `http://www.cambridgeimmerse.com/subjects-overview/` for what appears to be some kind of cookie checking system.